# Update table using select and where

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables:

```
table ficha_atendimento
int id
string cidadaos_cns

table cidadaos
int id
string cns
```

I need do create a column `int cidadaos_id` on table `ficha_atendimento_cidadao` and I like to fill it with the id from cidadaos table, like it:

```
insert into ficha_atendimento
set cidadao_id = select id from cidadaos where cidadaos.cns = ficha_atendimento.cns
```

But it's not works... Any help?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two separate operations to achieve that. Firstly, add the `cidadao_id` column to your table. Then, `UPDATE` its values from the `cidados` table:

```
ALTER TABLE ficha_atendimento ADD COLUMN cidadao_id INT NOT NULL;
UPDATE ficha_atendimento f
JOIN cidadaos c ON c.cns = f.cns
SET f.cidadao_id = c.id
```

You may also want to add a `FOREIGN KEY` on the `cidadao_id` value:

```
ALTER TABLE ficha_atendimento ADD FOREIGN KEY (cidadao_id) REFERENCES cidadaos(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want an `update`:

```
update ficha_atendimento fa join
       cidadaos c
       on c.cns = fa.cns
    set fa.cidadao_id = c.id ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The principles are:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...) SELECT column1, column2, column3, ... FROM table1 WHERE condition;
```

if you put according to the rules i think you can run your code. And plus if you have some data to demos it would be help.